# Is it possible to use MS access as a TFS client for Work Item tracking?

Tags: ms-access, tfs

Specifically I would like to create for the stakeholders, a simplified view of the work items different from the very detailed one used by the developer in VS. Ideally some fields like iteration path would also have to update tfs.

For now, I use [lists in excel](https://seesharper.wordpress.com/2009/08/18/tfs-and-excel-the-basics/) but would like to display details in more user friendly fashion using forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not out of the box. You have a few options for viewing / manipulating work items.

1. Visual Studio
2. Web (basically the same view as in VS but though a browser)
3. Excel
4. MS Project

If you want to produce a more user friendly UI than the view in Excel then I think you have 2 options.

1. Use VBA in Excel to create a "forms" interface, I haven't used VBA in years but I can't think of a reason why this wouldn't be fairly easy. The plus side to this approach is that you *should* be isolated from API changes to TFS when you migrate to newer versions. The downside is Excel.
2. Write a .net application and use the [TFS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to pull the required data from TFS. This would be the most elegant way from an engineering point of view, but you wouid almost certainly have to retest and possibly update the app when migrating to a newer version of TFS.